# How/from where did the the two TiPS components get the names Ralph and Norton?

Tags: history, space-tether

From [Gunter's Space Page](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/tips.htm):

> The TiPS (Tethers in Space Physics Satellite) satellite is a tether physics experiment consisting of two end masses connected by a 4 km non-conducting tether. The satellite was deployed on 20 June 1996 at an altitude of 1,022 kilometers.
>
> This experiment is designed to increase knowledge about gravity-gradient tether dynamics and the survivability of tethers in space. TiPS consist of two end masses separated by a four kilometer tether. The End masses, named **Ralph** (1a) and **Norton** (1b), weigh 37.7 and 10.8 kilograms, respectively.

How or from where did the the two TiPS (Tethers in Space Physics Satellite) components get the names Ralph and Norton?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ralph** Kramden and Ed **Norton** were two characters in a very early (1951-1955) TV sitcom called *The Honeymooners*. Bonus: The *New Horizons* satellite that flew past Pluto almost two years ago sported two experiments named **Ralph** and **Alice**, named after Ralph and Alice Kramden.

Comment: Which one was closer to the center of mass, Norton or Ralph?

Comment: It turns out that Ralph and Alice are on New Horizons! https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4288.pdf