# Why were Europe's first few satellites so stylish? Why the pronounced alternating white and black stripes?

Tags: artificial-satellite, history, spaceflight-firsts

In *The Century of Space Science*, edited by J.A. Bleeker, Johannes Geiss, M. Huber, viewed in [Google books](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=6aQRBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA52) I ran across the following text and images.

Both satellites are quite stylish looking and have very pronounced alternating white and black stripes.

Presumably the satellites would not be exposed until they are in space when the fairing or nose cone can open, so they would be too far away to see clearly in a telescope so that rotation or tumbling would be visible.

**Question:** Why were Europe's first few satellites so stylish? Why did they have very pronounced alternating white and black stripes, and had Vanguard-like antennas, but not its shiny reflective metallic finish<sup>1,2</sup>.

---

From pages 52 and 53:

[image: France's Astérix was a 42 kg test satellite]

> The fruits of these investments were soon to be seen. On 26 November 1965, a Diamant rocket rose from the Hammaguir launch pad and placed into orbit the first French satellite, significantly called *Astérix*. France thus became the third space power and confirmed its claim for an independent role in this important strategic field.
>
> *Astérix* was a 42 kg test satellite whose role was to confirm the rocket’s ability to place it into orbit.  Ten days later, on 6 December 1965, an American Scout rocket launched France’s first scientific satellite, FR-1. This satellite, weighing 60 kg, had been developed by CNES and carried instruments for studying ionization irregularities in the ionosphere and the magnetosphere. It was launched from Vandenberg and placed into a near-circular orbit.

---

[image: Italy's San Marco-1 satellite]

> Broglio was quick to react to NASA’s offer of collaboration in space research. In 1962, Italy and the USA signed an agreement for the so-called ‘San Marco’ project, and two eyars later, on 15 December 1964, the first Italian satellite, *San Marco-1*, was launched by a Scout rocket from Wallops Island. It was a sphere with a diameter of 66 cm and weighed no less than 115 kg. Built by the University of Rome’s Centro di Ricerche Aerospaziali under the direction of Broglio, this was the first all-European satellite to circle the Earth. A second San Marco satellite was launched by Broglio’s group  in 1967 from a platform anchored in the Indian Ocean off the coast of Kenya, and the programme continued in the following decade.

<sup>1</sup>[Puzzler: Is this a Sputnik?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19706/12102)

<sup>2</sup>[This BBC photo does not show a replica of Vanguard-1, what might it be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23286/12102)

Comment: Possibly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37554/6944

Comment: Related fact: Tracking of space objects is often done with optical telescopes [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Surveillance_Telescope), this was partially done to prevent unidentified space objects from [triggering missile alerts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Space_Surveillance_Network#Space_Surveillance_Telescope_program). When [SACI-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SACI-1) failed first contact, is was possible to identify that the panels had opened and the umbilical cable had been properly cut.

Comment: @Mefitico those links are compelling, but how are they related to this question post exactly? I'm missing the context. These may also be of interest: [What would be a “big picture” understanding of how the orbits of Earth satellites are monitored?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23012/12102) and also [Is there a satellite that tracks other satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27152/12102)

Comment: @uhoh I had a gut feeling about the answer, and planned to add one more reference, claiming this satellite was meant to validate the launcher only [here, but only found it in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ast%C3%A9rix_(satellite)). It has telemetry recorders on-board, but the transmission antennas failed (which engineers likely had foreseen). In the end, I was left with only the first intended comment, and lacked both good references and evidence pieces to reach any conclusion.

Comment: @Mefitico I only managed to get two cups of coffee this morning, so *only one of my two remaining neurons* is firing. Maybe you can still post a partial answer, which will give you more room to explain. Right now I don't see how telemetry recorders, transmission antennas and optical telescopes relate to these densely spaced stripes. If these where light/dark in quadrants and rotating like [spinsat](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16944/12102) I could see how telescopic observations might help, but these stripes are too tight to make a big difference in a telescope, no?

Comment: @uhoh: My guess is: The stripes are made for facilitating identification and assessment of the spacecraft attitude via optical telescopes. Radars work only for orbit, but they might confuse satellites with similar orbits and radar cross-section. Also, because it is an early experiment, both the injection orbit could be off-target and the antennas could have broken, making the telescope assessment a backup method. The lines are around the spin axis and large enough to differentiate at the perigee, but I'm missing a lot of research to uphold those claims.

Answer (score 7):

To address only Astérix: [Space Archaeology has a different picture and a writeup](https://spacearchaeology.org/?p=499):

[image]

> Weighing 42 kilograms, the satellite was a distinctive striped
>   fibreglass spinning-top shape half a meter in diameter, the black
>   stripes to provide passive thermal control.

I suspect the picture is of a replica, and this is not a primary source, but maybe it'll do until something better comes along.

Comment: "Thermal regulation" is always the throwdown answer!  I too would like to see more detail.

Comment: Nice find, thank you for posting! Now that we can see that the surface (at least of this likely replica) looks more like brushed metal than white paint, the surface looks much more like the other early satellites, but I don't see any of those reflections in the poor reproduction in the question, so we can't be sure yet I guess. The dark areas will absorb heat from the Sun more rapidly, but radiate it back into space more rapidly as well, so I'm not sure what the net effect will be on the spacecraft's temperature as it passes in and out of the Earth's shadow. Cool problem (pun intended).

Comment: I've just added a bounty in case "something better" has come along :-)

Answer (score 5):

Several of the early satellites, including the first US satellite, Explorer, used black and white stripes to control the satellite's temperature by adjusting the a/e (absorptivity-to-emissivity) ratio.  (Ref 1 and image below)  The white strips have low absorptivity and low emissivity while the black stripes have high absorptivity and high emissivity.  The first US satellite to use a thin film temperature control coating (rather than black and white stripes) was the Vanguard satellite launched in 1958 (Ref 2).  The Vanguard coating was developed by Thomas Cox and Alan Bradford under the direction of Georg Hass (Ref 3) working at the Ft. Belvoir Engineering Research and Development Laboratory that later became the Army Night Vision Laboratory.  Georg Hass also helped jump start optical thin film work at the newly formed NASA by mentoring James Heaney (Ref 4) at Goddard Space Flight Center.  Heaney became a leader in NASA's optical thin film application to many programs, including the James Webb Space Telescope and the temperature control coating for the Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe (Ref 5)

[image: Figure 1: The Explorer Satellite]

Much has changed in the last half century or so.  Spacecraft outer surface coatings, with few exceptions, must now be electrically conductive to minimize the possibility of ESD (electro-static discharge).  Many spacecraft don't have a thermal control coating, utilizing MLI (multi-layer insulation) instead.  You can see this MLI in the figure below showing the New Horizons spacecraft.  The gold color can be due to gold coated Mylar or aluminum coated Kapton (Ref. 6).  On the left is the RTG (radioisotope thermal generator) whose outer surface is black for maximum emission of heat into space.  On the upper right is the cold patch of the passive cooler for Ralph**.   The patch appears white in the visible so as not to overheat the sensitive detectors when in the inner solar system, but is very black (high emissivity) in the infrared, so cools the detectors to less than 135 K when in the outer solar system (Ref 7).  These are examples of three different kinds of thermal control surfaces: one black (emissive) at all wavelengths, one highly reflective at longer visible wavelengths and the infrared, and one highly reflective in the visible and highly emissive in the infrared.

** Ralph as in Ralph Kramden from the old Honeymooners show! (It's next to a UV spectrometer called Alice).

[image: MLI on New Horizons]

Ref 1 Spacecraft temperature control
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20010014168.pdf

Ref 2 First application of an optical thin film coating for satellite temperature control https://materion.com/-/media/files/advanced-materials-group/ac/ac-newsletter-article-pdfs/coatings-used-in-space_technical-paper.pdf

Ref 3 Georg Hass 
https://www.osa.org/en-us/history/biographies/bios/georg_hass/

Ref 4 James Heaney
https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/profile/James.Heaney-5357

Ref 5 Thermal control coating for the Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe 
James B. Heaney, Charles C. He, Wanda C. Peters, Robert R. Gorman, Samuel Dummer, Cliffton E. Jackson, J. T. VanSant, "Thermal radiative properties of the microwave anisotropy probe telescope," Proc. SPIE 4444, Optomechanical Design and Engineering 2001, (5 November 2001); https://doi.org/10.1117/12.447293

Ref. 6 Gold coatings and MLI
https://curiosity.com/topics/nasa-uses-gold-on-its-spacecraft-curiosity/

Ref. 7 Ralph on New Horizons
https://www.boulder.swri.edu/~tcase/SPIE_Ralph_final%20Reuter

Comment: 1) why not just use a single intermediate color instead of alternating white and black? (ditto [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38550/why-were-europes-first-few-satellites-so-stylish-why-the-pronounced-alternatin/41803#comment136463_41802)) 2) I am confused by the choice of the words "control" and "adjusting"; they just chose something and hoped it worked right? It's not like there was someone on the ground turning a knob which somehow changed the stripes while in orbit was there? Or does this refer to in-lab optimization preflight?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to paint fifty different test fixtures with different duty cycles from two cans of paint instead of mixing fifty shades of gray?

Comment: Remember, this was the time of the first man made satellites.  Not only was optical thin film technology in its infancy, the exact optical radiation environment at Low Earth Orbit (LEO) was only a guess at the time.  Now, the optical radiation environment is well known for virtually anywhere in the solar system.  We also have computers and software that can model a thin film stack for any optical properties you want.  The details of the temperature control coating may also vary with the application.  For example, in a Sun synchronous polar orbit, you always know where the Sun is.

Comment: Okay I've asked a new question: [Are black and white stripes any better than uniform gray for thermal control?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41806/12102)

Comment: Another Ralph reference: [How/from where did the the two TiPS components get the names Ralph and Norton?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21436/12102) Somewhat related: [Why are RTGs different colors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18100/12102) and [Why were early satellites produced with polished “mirror-like” surfaces?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24311/12102) and [How does the thin gold film in the glass of spacesuit helmets block thermal IR but transmit visible? What's the property?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32538/12102)

Comment: and [What are these very large, square panels on Inmarsat 5?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21524/12102) and [What is the function of this array of what looks like mirrors on TESS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26544/12102)

Comment: "On other satellites, such as Explorer 3, reflecting oxide stripes maintain the average inside temperature between reasonable limits; 30 and 100 degrees Fahrenheit." https://youtu.be/PZiTKXTKa9Q?t=469

Answer (score 2):

"The answer is always thermal control"

San Marco-1

> The satellite had black and white longitudinal sections painted on
>   its surface for thermal control.

[NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive / San Marco 1](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1964-084A)

Asterix-1

> This was the first French satellite, launched in 1965. It's painted with stripes as a form of temperature control - the black absorbs heat, the white reflects.

[Australian Broadcasting Company](https://www.abc.net.au/triplej/programs/hack/the-archaeology-of-satellites-and-orbital-space-junk/8121340)

Comment: "For thermal control" isn't completely satisfying me, I gotta wonder why they didn't just grab a can of gray paint instead of "the pronounced alternating white and black stripes". I still think that "Europe's first few satellites were so stylish" for a reason. However there may be more details in the links. *Thanks!*

Comment: I'd like more too. There's an informative book about the San Marco project on NTRS here: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740004978.pdf but sadly it doesn't even mention the passive thermal control system.  Asterix was very hard to find details on.

Comment: Okay I've asked a new question: [Are black and white stripes any better than uniform gray for thermal control?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41806/12102)